# Latex- flipping figures

Tags: latex, subfigure

How can I flip a figure in my LaTeX file around horizontal axis? The figures reside in subfigure.

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is the solution:

add to preamble

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

then the following does the trick.

```
\scalebox{1}[-1]{ \includegraphics[width=0.50\columnwidth] {test.eps} }
```